# Moving deletions to a branch in git

Tags: git

There's a number of times in the past couple of months where I've developed code for a feature, committed the feature to the git repository and then at some later date decided to remove some of those features. What I end up having to do in order to keep the code base clean is delete a file or parts of files that were committed to git and commit those changes.

However, in the interest of having the deleted code easily reinstated at a later date, I go through an additional step of cloning the repository elsewhere, checking out the commit prior to the delete, copying over the files that were changed (using ditto or even manually sometimes) and then committing the changes to a new branch. This additional step gives me ability to have the deleted feature abstracted in a branch and reinstate the feature into the codebase quite easily at a later stage by merging the branch.

Is this a common practice and more importantly am I missing a git feature that allows me to do this out of the box. If so, what is command to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you’re working in Git’s git repository and you have a bright idea.

```
$ git rm -rf Documentation
$ git commit -m 'Documentation is for the weak'
```

That results in the following history. (Note: [`git lol`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) is a non-standard but highly useful alias.)

```
$ git lol
* d55a922 (HEAD, master) Documentation is for the weak
*   443d803 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge branch 'maint'
|\
| * 8d44277 (origin/maint) Update draft release notes to 1.8.1.5
| *   6f0c336 Merge branch 'ef/non-ascii-parse-options-error-diag' into maint
| |\
...
```

To give yourself a mulligan, checkout a branch at your newly minted commit and revert there.

```
$ git checkout -b mulligan/delete-all-documentation
$ git revert --no-edit HEAD
```

Now with

```
$ git checkout master
```

you can go back to work.

Say you add a new commit to master, then your history becomes

```
$ git lola
* b4d76d9 (HEAD, master) Add new feature X
| * 84b0e21 (mulligan/delete-all-documentation) Revert "Documentation is for the weak"
|/
* d55a922 Documentation is for the weak
| *   46b564f (origin/pu) Merge branch 'pc/subtree-add-before-fetch' into pu
...
```

This is not a common practice. Reinstating the feature will be quite easy only if the `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` goes cleanly, that is if no other changes have been applied to the code where you removed the old feature. Look down the road to see how poorly this will scale. To reinstate old features, developers will have to sift through a bunch of branches to find the right one to resurrect. Git has *excellent* support for searching history, which we see from the lack of these long-lived mulligan branches being a common practice.

Answer (score 3):

`git checkout <sha1> filepath/filename` takes the file from the revision sha1 into your working copy.

`git revert` is to revert changes made by a commit(s) including merge commits. You could also revert reverts.

No clones please, as it is too heavy process, checkout works much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'd like to clarify that I would like the deletions to appear as a branch. With git checkout and revert I'd have to know the commit, which isn't easily known to another developer or explicit seen when viewing the commit tree. Will take on board the clone tip

Comment: @sfk Not sure that do you mean... Branch just a label for a human to a particular commit sha1. So you could create a branch by `git branch some_branch <sha1>` and when do the same using the branch name instead of <sha1>. Could you give more details to the exact problem, maybe some example?